# Confused about writing a ListADT that stores Characters

Tags: java, arraylist

So for this project I'm working on, I need to write the implementation for a ListADT that stores Characters. I'm pretty confused at how to approach/implement these methods. Especially for the one that is supposed to return the capacity of the array-list, which is different than the number of elements contained in the array-list. I need some help. Here's the skeleton for some context:

```
public interface ListADT {

     * Remove all the elements of this list. Position and number of elements are
     * updated but the capacity remains unchanged.
     * Given ListADT bl == 3< b | a >
     *  When bl.clear()
     *  Then bl == 3< | >
     *   
     * Given ListADT bl == 3< | >
     *  When bl.clear()
     *  Then bl == 3< | >
     * }
    public ListADT clear();

     * get the current character. If it is not possible to get the current
     * character, throw an IllegalGetException.
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< b | a >
     *  When Character val = bl.get()
     *  Then val == 'a'
     * }
    public Character get()
        throws IllegalGetException;

     * Get the current capacity of the list.
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< | b , a >
     *  When int val = bl.getCapacity()
     *  Then val == 5
     * }
    public Integer getCapacity();

     * get the number of elements in the list.
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< | b , a >
     *  When int val = bl.getNumElts()
     *  Then val == 2
     *  
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< | >
     *  When int val = bl.getNumElts()
     *  Then val == 0
     * }
    public Integer getNumElts();

     * get the current position of the list.
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< b | a >
     *  When int val = bl.getPosition()
     *  Then val == 1
     * }
    public Integer getPosition();

     * insert c into this ListADT at the current position. If the number of elements in the list
     * is equal to the capacity of the list (i.e., the list is full), then the
     * list should increase capacity by one to allow the insert.
     * Given ListADT bl == 2< b | a >
     *  When bl.insert('x')
     *  Then bl == 3< b | x , a >
     * }
    public ListADT insert(Character c);

     * move the current position to position 0 (the first position) of the list.
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< b , a | >
     *  When bl.moveToFirst()
     *  Then bl == 5< | b , a >
     * }
    public void moveToFirst();

     * move the current position one spot closer to the tail of the list.
     * Remember that the last possible position is just after the last element.
     * If it is not possible to move to the next position, leave the list as it
     * is (do nothing).
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< | b , a >
     *  When bl.next()
     *  Then bl == 5< b | a >
     * }
     * 
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< b , a | >
     *  When bl.next()
     *  Then bl == 5< b , a | >
     * }
    public void next();

     * move the current position one spot closer to the head of the list. If it
     * is not possible to move to the previous position, leave the list as it is
     * (do nothing).
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< b , a | >
     *  When bl.prev()
     *  Then bl == 5< b | a >
     *  
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< | b , a >
     *  When bl.prev()
     *  Then bl == 5< | b , a >
     * }
    public void prev();

     * remove the current element from this ListADT. See chapter 5 for details
     * on the remove operation. If it is not possible to remove the current
     * element, then leave the list alone (do nothing).
     * Given ListADT bl == 5< b | a >
     *  When bl.remove()
     *  Then bl == 5< b | >
     * }
    public ListADT remove();

     * Change the capacity of this list to c. If c is less than the current
     * capacity, throw away any extra elements. If one of the extra elements was
     * the current element, then set the position to after the new last element.
     * Given ListADT bl == 3< b | a >
     *  When bl.resize(5)
     *  Then bl == 5< b | a >
     *   
     * Given ListADT bl == 3< b | a >
     *  When bl.resize(1)
     *  Then bl == 1< b | >
     * }
    public ListADT resize(int c);
}
```